# SQL query to find only those customer ids which have 2 source values

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

I have 2 tables, one which stores the customer id and the other table which stores customer id along with the information about different sources which use that customer information. Example:
TABLE A

```
Customer Id
1
2
3
..
```

TABLE B

```
Customer Id Source
1            'AA'
2            'AA'
1            'AB'
2            'AB'
2            'AC'
3            'AA'
3            'AB'
3            'AE'
4            'AA'
4            'AB'
```

I want to write a SQL query which returns records which have only AA and AB as sources (no other sources)

I have written the below query, but it is not working correctly:

```
select a.customer_id
  from A a, B b
 where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
   and b.source IN ('AA','AB')
 group by a.customer_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather efficient solution is a couple of `exists` subqueries:

```
select a.*
from a
where
    exists(select 1 from b where b.customer_id = a.customer_id and b.source = 'AA')
    and exists(select 1 from b where b.customer_id = a.customer_id and b.source = 'AB')
    and not exists(select 1 from b where b.customer_id = a.customer_id and b.source not in ('AA', 'AB'))
```

With an index on `b(customer_id, source)`, this should run quickly.

Another option is aggreation:

```
select customer_id
from b
group by customer_id
having
    max(case when source = 'AA' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
    and max(case when source = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
    and max(case when source not in ('AA', 'AB') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this should work, exists and not exists in combination. I will learn more on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select b.customer_id
from b
where b.source in ('AA', 'AB')
group by b.customer_id
having count(distinct b.source) = 2;
```

That said, your version *should* work.  However, you should learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  The join, however, is not needed in this case.

If you want *only* those two sources, you need to tweak the logic:

```
select b.customer_id
from b
group by b.customer_id
having sum(case when b.source = 'AA' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- has AA
       sum(case when b.source = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- has AB
       count(distinct b.source) = 2;
```

Comment: Does this solution ensures that no other source exists than 'AA' and 'AB'?

Comment: Records with first source as AA and second source as AC and no other sources are also being returned.

Comment: @AlokMathur . . . I missed that part of the requirement, but updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that the customer_id/source combination has no duplicates

```
select a.customer_id
  from A a join B b
    on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
 group by a.customer_id
-- both 'AA' and 'AB', but no other
having sum(case when b.source IN ('AA','AB') then 1 else -1 end) = 2
```

It might be more efficient to aggregate before the join:

```
select a.customer_id
from A a join 
  ( select customer_id
    from B b
    group by customer_id
    -- both 'AA' and 'AB', but no other
    having sum(case when source IN ('AA','AB') then 1 else -1 end) = 2
  ) b
on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
```